# Is it possible to delete a SharePoint Online site using Microsoft flows or by using any Rest API

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I tried creating a SharePoint Online site using Microsoft flows and it was successful.
Now, I'm looking to delete a SharePoint Online site by same flow.
While creating the site we use RestApi call but for deleting a SharePoint Site I was using below api call
/_api/SPSiteManager/Delete

Encountered the error given below:

The parameter 'SiteId' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the function import 'Delete'.
clientRequestId: 822eed70-5fdc-4e45-bd37-3f2de1f47ad7
serviceRequestId: 519fd89f-f0c1-0000-a449-e1c290d37d81

Can anyone look into my request.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a Microsoft Graph API call like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) one. Every SharePoint document library is a drive within OneDrive. Drives are accessed as **/drives/** - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request-3) for documentation. OneDrive for Business can be accessed as **/me/drive** as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

try with a lowercase "s" for siteId parameter

Regards